# Easiest CentOS control panel

Tags: centos, centos5

Which CentOS control panel is easiest to use? I don't need a panel for clients or resellers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualmin/webmin

Answer (score 0):

try ispconfig, I've been using it a lot recently and so far it's got everything I need

http://www.ispconfig.org/